# Replacement for File::mime() in Laravel 4 (to get mime type from file extension)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Laravel 3 had a **[File::mime()](http://three.laravel.com/docs/files#mime)** method which made it easy to get a file's mime type from its extension:

```
$extension = File::extension($path);
$mime = File::mime($extension);
```

On upgrading to Laravel 4 I get an error:

**Call to undefined method Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::mime()**

I also can't see any mention of mime types in the [Filesystem API docs](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Filesystem.Filesystem.html).

What's the recommended way to get a file's mime type in Laravel 4 (please note this is not a user-uploaded file)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One solution I've found is to use the [Symfony HttpFoundation File class](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html) (which is already included as a dependency in Laravel 4):

```
$file = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File($path);
$mime = $file->getMimeType();
```

And in fact the File class uses the [Symfony MimeTypeGuesser](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/MimeType/MimeTypeGuesser.html) class so this also works:

```
$guesser = Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\MimeTypeGuesser::getInstance();
echo $guesser->guess($path);
```

But unfortunately I'm getting unexpected results: I'm getting **text/plain** instead of **text/css** when passing a path to a css file.

Comment: It seems from [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686901/) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226289/) that this isn't a reliable method.

Comment: The same problem with text/plain instead of tons of other formats. js, txt, xls, po etc. - all get text/plain mimes

Answer (score 7):

IF you had just uploaded the file you can use:

```
Input::file('field_name')->getMimeType();
```

You can see more [here](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files)! I hope it be for some help! :D

EDIT:
`Input::file` is some kind of extention from `File`, so you may use `File::get('file')->getMimeType();` also. Didn't test, but MUST work.

Comment: thanks, but as stated I want to use this for any general file, not one that has just been uploaded.

Comment: thanks. But File::get() returns a string, so it is not possible to call getMimeType(). Also, Symfony's getMimeType() is not proving reliable for the CSS file type I need it to work for (see my own answer).

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be a bug on Laravel I guess. Have you looked on Laravel's GitHub repository? You should look into the issue traking, see if you find something!

Comment: That method is unreliable. And useless as a result.

Answer (score 6):

After reading that:

- PHP **[mime_content_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)** is deprecated
- Its replacement **[FileInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226289/php-doesnt-return-the-correct-mime-type)** is unreliable
- Symfony's **[getMimeType()](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html)** uses FileInfo (see my other answer)

I decided instead to port Laravel 3's implementation of **File::mime()** into a helper library within my Laravel 4 application. The Laravel 3 implementation just reads the MIME types from a config lookup array, based on file extension.

Solution:

- Copied **application/config/mimes.php** from my L3 project to **app/config/mimes.php** in my L4 project
- Made a FileHelper library with the File::mime() function code from the **[Laravel 3 File class](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v3.2.14/laravel/file.php)**.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that Symfony `ExtensionGuesser` and `MimeTypeGuesser` use unreliable `FileInfo` class. For that reason validation of mimes return unpredictable results and can not be used with files uploads in a proper way (it returns `text/plain` mime for `js`, `xls`, `po` etc.).

I've found very simple solution for this problem.

Instead of

```
'attachment' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,doc,docx,zip,rar,pdf,rtf,xlsx,xls,txt|max:10000',
```

I split that into two different parts and now my validation looks like this:

```
private function createFileAttachmentValidator($file)
{
    return Validator::make(
        [
            'attachment' => $file,
            'extension'  => \Str::lower($file->getClientOriginalExtension()),
        ],
        [
            'attachment' => 'required|max:10000',
            'extension'  => 'required|in:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,doc,docx,zip,rar,pdf,rtf,xlsx,xls,txt',
        ],
        $this->validationMessages()
    );          
}
```

I simply try to verify that extension of the file is present and that it is listed in my `in` rule. That works, however, solution is not perfect.

Comment: Using this along with built in mime validation is best way to tackle this.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function mimeType($path)
{
    return finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $path);
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/illuminate/filesystem/blob/master/Filesystem.php#L194