# mime type validation in laravel 4 doesn't work

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, mime-types

I'm trying to validate the file size and the mime type of an uploaded file (mp3 file) in laravel. But the validation only seem to kick in when I upload an image (gif, png). When I upload an mkv file with a size of 100Mb the validation seems to be ok with it. Here's my current code:

```
$file = Input::file('audio_file');
$file_rules = array('audio_file' => 'size:5242880|mimes:mp3'); //also tried mpeg

$file_validator = Validator::make(Input::file(), $file_rules);

if($file_validator->fails()){
 //return validation errors
}else{
 //always goes here and succeeds
}
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks to me like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564029/file-upload-mime-type-validation-with-laravel-4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the file rules line to:

```
$file_rules = array('audio_file' => 'size:5242880|mimes:audio/mpeg,audio/mp3,audio/mpeg3');
```

According to [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3003), 'audio/mpeg' is the correct MIME type for mp3 files (some browsers also use 'audio/mpeg3' or 'audio/mp3').

If that doesn't work, you could get the MIME type before validation:

```
$file = Input::file('audio_file');
$mimeType = $file->getMimeType();
$supportedTypes = ['audio/mpeg', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/mp3'];

if (in_array($mimeType, $supportedTypes)) {
    // validate or simply check the file size here
} else {
    // do some other stuff
}
```

Comment: looks like the file that I'm trying to upload for testing the validation is an unknown mime-type. That's why calling the `getMimeType()` method results in an error. I tried with a `.png` and it works. How do I add custom mime types?

Comment: My guess would be either changing or extending MimeTypeExtensionGuesser class (located at 'vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType'). That way you could add some types that are missing or changing the file type for existing ones. AFAIK, there is no way to add new custom types.

Comment: You could add custom mime types by adding them in an array to `app/mimes.php` in Laravel 3, not sure about Laravel 4.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer does not work: `$file->getMimeType()` returns unpredictable results. Files like `.css`, `.js`, `.po`, `.xls` and much more get `text/plain` mime type. So I've posted my solution there https://stackoverflow.com/a/26299430/1331510