# Laravel Multiple Validator Wrong Error Message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Problem : When uploaded file exceeds 5000kb, validator returns the 'required' message instead of 'max' message. Why ?

```
$file = (Input::file('inputName'));
$fileValidator = Validator::make(
   array('Field Name' => $file),
   array('Field Name' => 'required|max:5000|mimes:jpeg,png,bmp')
);

if($fileValidator->fails()){
   return $fileValidator->errors()->all(':message');
}
```

---

Update : This problem occurs especially *.psd files' validation.

---

Update 2 : when i var_dump($file), i can see that;

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#9 (7) {
  ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(52) "4-47970_rsasecurityanalyticsevolutionofsiemebook.pdf"
  ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(24) "application/octet-stream"
  ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(0)
  ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(1)
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

As you can see, the pathName and fileName looks null. So that's why laravel returns required message. Here's the new question : why is the fileName is null ?

Comment: Please can you replace `Field Name` with actual field name you name in the form

Comment: @Digitlimit i already changed it.

Comment: can you do `dd(Input::file('inputName'));` just to confirm the file was submitted?

Comment: @Digitlimit, it is confirmed, file is submitted, can get its values with var_dump(Input::file('inputName')). also gets the mime type as like following : application/pdf, image/png etc.

Comment: how about including `psd` in mimes type like so: `mimes:jpeg,png,bmp,psd`

Comment: @Digitlimit, i just want to upload jpeg, png and bmp files. Not psd files. But  testing upload with psd files returns me the :max error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mime type validation in laravel 4 doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981739/mime-type-validation-in-laravel-4-doesnt-work)

Comment: you can also try: `mimes:image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp`

Comment: see list of other possible mimes type : http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you upload a file more than the allowed size (max post size and max upload size), then php does not send it to the server, that is why your code does not get file and through an error of required.

go to your php.ini and increase the limit of max upload and max post size. this should solve your issue.

you can also set these by php:

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');
```

or you can edit your php.ini file for these:

```
post_max_size = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```