# Laravel MIME validation - disallowed extension goes through when file is not empty

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.2. For one of my forms I have these validation rules for a file:

```
$rules = array('file' => 'required|mimes:pdf,jpg,png,docx');
```

So a simple whitelist of extensions. Then, I validate the field as follows:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // redirect with errors
}
```

Now, I'm trying to test it, so I upload a file from out of the whitelist - an *empty* JS file (test.js) - and the validation fails, which is OK. But *as soon as I put some content in the same JS file*, the upload goes through, even if the file MIME type is the same ("application/javascript").

Tried it with an SQL file (test.sql) - the same. Validation works properly only for the empty file.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've heard before that the `mimes` rule is a bit buggy.

A solution is offered in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681854/replacement-for-filemime-in-laravel-4-to-get-mime-type-from-file-extension/26299430#26299430)