# Why is Symfony2 File->getMimeType() returning text/plain not text/css for a CSS file?

Tags: php, symfony

I need to get the MIME type of a file on the server. I'm using Laravel but want to use the File class from Symfony HTTPFoundation (see my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681854)).

When I use **[File->GetMimeType()](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html#method_getMimeType)** on a css file, **text/plain** is returned when I'm expecting **text/css**.

```
$file = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File($path); //pass CSS file
$mime = $file->getMimeType(); //returns text/plain
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226289/php-doesnt-return-the-correct-mime-type

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to this question and simple solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26299430/1331510

However, my approach is not perfect, but it works for file uploads: just extract file extension from file name and check its presence in and array with `in:pdf,csv,css,..` rule.