# Symfony2 Restrict end user to upload only csv file

Tags: php, symfony, csv, doctrine-orm

In my symfony2 application, I am using doctrine and I want user to upload only csv file.

Below is my code I have set for validation in my entity file:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\File( maxSize = "1024k", mimeTypes = {"text/csv"}, mimeTypesMessage = "Please   upload a valid CSV File")
 * @ORM\Column(name="filename", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $filename;
```

But still its not allowing me to upload the csv file too.

Comment: I don't see any problem with this. The upload is going on when you remove the mimeTypes condition ?

Comment: @Debflav, Yes if I remove that condition then its working for me.

Comment: maybe try to remove the condition and check the `MimeTypes` of the file that you are uploading.

Comment: Try this message maybe : _"The mime type of the file is invalid ({{ type }}). Allowed mime types are {{ types }}"_

Comment: @ra_htial, Already did that before posting the question here. Its showing me text/csv itself. i.e. Its a valid file. I checked it with the below code in my controller action :
[code] \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($csvLoader->getFilename()->getClientMimeType())

Comment: try to debug the `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\FileValidator`

Comment: @ra_htial, As I am new in Symfony2, can you please elaborate me with some example code?

Comment: So that file will test your File rules, so go through the execution and `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump` the `mimetypes` and see where the validation returns `true` and doesn't raise a `vaiolation`

Comment: @ra_htial, I apologize, but I am still not getting what you mean and what you want me to debug and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your comment : ***"The mime type of the file is invalid ("text/plain"). Allowed mime types are "text/csv"***.

After some search, Symfony 2 is using the [finfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) function. You can read [Php doesn't return the correct mime type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5226315/3361444) :

Pekka 웃: *"I'm not intimately familiar with the workings of fileinfo, but I think this is normal. Text files (and that's what CSS and JS are) provide no clear pointers as to what content it has. They have no header bytes, no defined structure. So all poor fileinfo can do is guess - with poor results, as you can see.*

*I think to successfully verify the contents of .js and .css files, you have to either rely on the extension, or actually parse them with the correct, appropriate parser."*

So this is **not a bug** and the only way is to implement your own logic (in your FormBuilder) or like tutty said you can create your custom constraint.

**Edit**:

Following your comment, here's where Symfony 2 finfo() is used:
[Component/HttpFoundation/File/MimeType/FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/MimeType/FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser.php)

Comment: Can you please share the link where you found out that Symfony2 uses 
    `finfo()`.

Comment: Ok thanks. Based on the references, currently lets consider this as a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your file has another mime-type (probably text/plain). You should validate the file content instead. You can read more about custom validators here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: I thought too the problem can be the mime-type but the OP has already checked this. Btw not my downvote.

Comment: @Debflav,@Debflav, If I will do it using custom constraint, then it will be working. But I want to have it work without using custom constraint. I am not getting why my file's mime-type is text/plain although I am trying to upload the csv file and even when I check the mime type in controller using the below code:
    `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($csvLoader->getFilename()->getClientMimeType());`

Comment: @KrishDamani Sometimes it appears that the wrong mime-type is returned to the app. If it's the case, one way is to use custom constraints. But you have already checked and it's 'text/csv'.

Comment: @Debflav, Yes as mentioned above when using this line of code in my controller action 
    `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($csvLoader->getFilename()->getClientMimeType(‌​));`
its showing me text/csv. And in the error message its showing me as the below text: 
`The mime type of the file is invalid ("text/plain"). Allowed mime types are "text/csv"`